# How do I align a component to another like in maya or max?

Tags: vertices

I'll be more specific so it's easier to understand my question :

Let's say that Vertex 1 is at coordinates X:0, Y:1, Z:0
and Vertex 2 is at coordinates X:1, Y:0, Z:0

I need vertex 1 to be aligned with vertex 2 on the X axis. Is there a shortcut/key/tool to do that or do I have to get into the vertex's coordinates each time i need to align?

In Maya, i'd just click on the desired axis, then hold V and translate vertex 2 towards vertex 1 and it would align perfectly.

Comment: select the verteces you want to be aligned > S to scale > choose the axis by pressing X Y or Z > hit 0. Verteces should be aligned in that axis. Is that enough or you need more complicated align?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone experiencing the same issue as I did: enable vertex snap, then drag your vertex along the desired axis while aiming your cursor at the target vertex.

Comment: That seems intuitive enough to me. What is your grief with it and how would you improve it ?

Comment: Worked with all dcc's before as well and I'm waaaaay faster using blender for a lot of modeling tasks - it's an endless and useless discussion. Also consider that this is not a regular forum, it's a Q&A site, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer